# "Sometimes when I click sleep, the screen turns dark but the fan will start spinning at high speed and the light is still blue"

Tags: sentence-construction, conditionals

Is this sentence grammatically correct? There are two conditionals

> Sometimes when I click sleep, the screen turns dark but the fan will start spinning at high speed and the light is still blue (supposed to be orange).

Comment: Where are the conditionals? We'd probably say, "Sometimes when I click 'sleep', although the screen goes dark, the fan starts spinning at high speed; and the light, which is meant to turn orange, stays blue."

Comment: ***when I click sleep*** is a "parenthetical" adverbial element. It should either be set off by leading *and* trailing commas, or no commas at all.